# need footer information in the header section in jQuery dataTables

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jQuery dataTables.

Due to large number of records, I need footer information "Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries (filtered from 3352 total entries)" in the header section after the "Show Entries" text.

Please suggest how can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Code I am using like this:

```
<img src="<?=PIXEL;?>" onload="initializeDataTables('user_listing'); $('.yournet_button').button();"/>


function initializeDataTables(divid)
{
    $('#'+divid).dataTable( {
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]],
            "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    } );
}
```

used:

- **File**: jquery.dataTables.js
- **Version**: 1.6.2

Comment: use ajax base searching in datatables

Comment: Thanks for the response, 

we are enable to view the header and and footer section. with using <img src="<?=PIXEL;?>" onload="initializeDataTables('user_listing'); $('.yournet_button').button();"/> we are loading the data, header and footer data displaying from the jquert.dataTables.js table

Comment: can you pls share jsfiddle of it?

Answer (score 1):

here you just need to pass `"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'` while calling datatables... see below code

```
function initializeDataTables(divid)
{
    $('#'+divid).dataTable( {
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]],
            "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
    } );
}
```

see [this](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan, I modified the code and tested, But it couldn't effect the functionality.